# Actual need of Zookeepers

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to HBase and I am still learning it. I just wanted to know that how many Zookeepers do we actually need?
 Is it one per regionserver or one per cluster?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zookeeper is per cluster, and not per regionserver.

From [The hbase definitive guide](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html):

> How many ZooKeepers should I run? You can run a ZooKeeper ensemble
>   that comprises 1 node only but in production it is recommended that
>   you run a ZooKeeper ensemble of 3, 5 or 7 machines; the more members
>   an ensemble has, the more tolerant the ensemble is of host failures.
>   Also, run an odd number of machines. In ZooKeeper, an even number of
>   peers is supported, but it is normally not used because an even sized
>   ensemble requires, proportionally, more peers to form a quorum than an
>   odd sized ensemble requires. For example, an ensemble with 4 peers
>   requires 3 to form a quorum, while an ensemble with 5 also requires 3
>   to form a quorum. Thus, an ensemble of 5 allows 2 peers to fail, and
>   thus is more fault tolerant than the ensemble of 4, which allows only
>   1 down peer.
>
> Give each ZooKeeper server around 1GB of RAM, and if possible, its own
>   dedicated disk (A dedicated disk is the best thing you can do to
>   ensure a performant ZooKeeper ensemble). For very heavily loaded
>   clusters, run ZooKeeper servers on separate machines from
>   RegionServers (DataNodes and TaskTrackers).